# add_row with group_by nest tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, tibble

I am trying to add_row() to grouped data **without** using do.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)


my.data <- data.frame(

  supplier = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b"),
  date = rep(c("2017-06-01","2017-03-01","2017-02-01","2017-01-12",
               "2017-05-01","2017-04-01"), 2), 
  order = c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0)

)
```

**Solution with do**

```
my.data %>%
  group_by(supplier) %>% 
  do(add_row(.,.before=0))
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   supplier [3]
   supplier       date order
      <chr>      <chr> <dbl>
 1     <NA>       <NA>    NA
 2        a 2017-06-01     1
 3        a 2017-03-01     0
 4        a 2017-02-01     0
 5        a 2017-01-12     1
 6        a 2017-05-01     1
 7        a 2017-04-01     0
 8     <NA>       <NA>    NA
 9        b 2017-06-01     0
10        b 2017-03-01     1
11        b 2017-02-01     0
12        b 2017-01-12     0
13        b 2017-05-01     1
14        b 2017-04-01     0
```

**Attempt with nest and mutate or purrr::map**

```
my.data %>%
  group_by(supplier) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(extra.row = add_row(data, .before = 0))
```

*Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Unsupported index type: NULL.*

Any suggestions. do is very slow when scaled.

Comment: You want the entire row to be NA, even the grouping var(s)?

Comment: The intent is to add_row with date value that is 30 days before the minimum date per group.   add_row(data, date = (min(.$date) - 30), .before=0)

Comment: Ok, a join should do it, I guess. I don't use the tidyverse so can't make an answer. You should probably clarify that the "solution with do" in the question isn't a solution (since supplier and date are NA)..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could bind a summarized dataset onto the original using `bind_rows`.

You may also be able to use `complete`, although right now your dates per group are the same and it might not work as written for different dates per group.  Also, I believe `complete` tends to be slow when you scale up.

Both solutions hinge on `date` being an actual `date` variable in the original dataset.

```
my.data = mutate(my.data, date = as.Date(date) )
```

Summarizing and binding with `summarize` and `bind_rows`.  The `arrange` is to get things in order, and could very well not be needed in the real case.

```
my.data %>%
    group_by(supplier) %>%
    summarize(date = min(date) - 30) %>%
    bind_rows(., my.data) %>%  
    arrange(supplier, date)
```

Using `complete` if dates are the same among groups.

```
my.data %>%
    group_by(supplier) %>%
    complete(date = c(min(.$date) - 30, .$date ) )
```

Result for both:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   supplier [2]
   supplier       date order
     <fctr>     <date> <dbl>
 1        a 2016-12-13    NA
 2        a 2017-01-12     1
 3        a 2017-02-01     0
 4        a 2017-03-01     0
 5        a 2017-04-01     0
 6        a 2017-05-01     1
 7        a 2017-06-01     1
 8        b 2016-12-13    NA
 9        b 2017-01-12     0
10        b 2017-02-01     0
11        b 2017-03-01     1
12        b 2017-04-01     0
13        b 2017-05-01     1
14        b 2017-06-01     0
```

Comment: I like the bind_rows() answer . It will work for my what I need. Thanks for the assistance, much appreciated.

Comment: `bind_rows` to the original dataset is a clever solution for a wide range of problems, I'm sure. Altogether a clever workaround.